# Php request receiving data but not setting Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have following form in my php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
   <title>SportsReg</title>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   <link rel="icon" href="./img/logo2.png"/>
   <!--bootstrap   -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!--JQUERY AND popper   -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--JQUERY AND bootstrap.js   -->
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='index.css'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='request.css'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='footer.css'>

</head>
<body>

<?php
ob_start();

if(!array_key_exists("clubloggedin", $_SESSION)){
   header("Location: ./index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
   exit;
}

require_once("./homeheader.php");
require_once("./db.php");


if (isset($_REQUEST["logout"]))
{
   // remove all session variables
   session_unset();

// destroy the session
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: ./index.php");
   exit();
}
$req_er = "";
if (isset($_REQUEST["next"])){
   $_SESSION["sport"] = $_REQUEST["sports"];
   $_SESSION["cid"] = $_REQUEST["category"];
   $_SESSION["pid"] = $_REQUEST["product"];
   $query="Select * from category where category_id = \"{$_SESSION["cid"]}\";";
   $pdata = db::getInstance()->get_result($query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pdata))
   {
       $_SESSION["cname"] = $row["category_name"];
   }
   $query="Select * from products where product_id = \"{$_SESSION["pid"]}\";";
   $pdata = db::getInstance()->get_result($query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pdata))
   {
       $_SESSION["pname"] = $row["product_name"];
   }
}

?>
<div class="container" id="reqform-container">

   <div class="container pl-5 pr-0" id="outline-request">
       <div class="row mt-5 mb-3 pt-5 pb-2 col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">    
           <h3 id="req-head"><?php echo($_SESSION["sport"]) ?> - <?php echo($_SESSION["cname"]) ?> - <?php echo($_SESSION["pname"]) ?></h3>
       </div>    
       <div class="row d-flex col-12 px-0 justify-content-center">
           <form class="col-12 px-0" action="./requestforms/generic1submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="detail-form">
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
               <input type="number" class=" reqinput-border form-control ml-3 col-11 col-md-6" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
               <input type="text" class=" reqinput-border form-control ml-3 col-11 col-md-6" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Color" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
               <input type="text" class=" reqinput-border form-control ml-3 col-11 col-md-6" id="size" name="size" placeholder="Size" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
               <textarea class=" reqinput-border form-control ml-3 col-11 col-md-6" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Other information (Max 190 characters)" rows="5" maxlength="191"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
               <input class=" reqinput-border form-control ml-3 col-11 col-md-6" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".txt,.xlsx,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,.pptx,.doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-12 justify-content-center">
                    <?php echo($req_er) ;?>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row d-flex col-xs-10 col-md-9 justify-content-end">
               <button type="submit" id = "req-btn" name="send-req" class="row col-8 col-md-3 btn btn-default">Send Request</button>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>

</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<?php
require_once("./footer.php");
?>
<!-- Footer -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle0" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle0">Product Request</h5>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
     Thanks for your request. You will receive your offers in a short time.
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>

<script src="header.js"></script>
<script src="request.js"></script>
</html>
```

when I submit the form I receive data in $_REQUEST but submit button $_REQUEST["send-req"] doesn't get set. I have used var_dump on $_REQUEST and $_POST and it displays values of all other parameters correctly but doesn't include "send-req" parameter.

Below is code for "generic1submit.php"

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();
if(!array_key_exists("clubloggedin", $_SESSION)){
    header("Location: ./index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
    exit;
}

require_once("../db.php");

if(isset($_REQUEST["send-req"]))
{
  $_SESSION["reqquantity"]= $_REQUEST["quantity"];
  $_SESSION["reqcolor"]= $_REQUEST["color"];
  $_SESSION["reqsize"]= $_REQUEST["size"];
  $_SESSION["reqdescription"]= $_REQUEST["description"];
  $target_dir = "requestuploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $newname = "";
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $info = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
  $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
  $nameid = uniqid();
  $newname = $nameid.".".$ext; 
  $target = 'requestuploads/'.$newname;
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target);
  $query="INSERT INTO club_requests(sports, category_id, product_id, quantity, color, size, description,club_id,filename) VALUES (\"{$_SESSION["sport"]}\",\"{$_SESSION["cid"]}\",\"{$_SESSION["pid"]}\",\"{$_REQUEST["quantity"]}\",\"{$_REQUEST["color"]}\",\"{$_REQUEST["size"]}\",\"{$_REQUEST["description"]}\",\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["club_id"]}\", \"$newname\");";
  db::getInstance()->dbquery($query);
  header("Location: ../userhome.php");
  exit();
}


?>
```

and here is code of request.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var scount = 0;
    $("#detail-form").submit(function(e) {
        if(scount==0)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{
            scount = 0;
            return true;
        }
        scount = 1;
        $("#exampleModalScrollable0").modal('show');
        $('#exampleModalScrollable0').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#detail-form").submit();    
        });
        
    });
});
```

Comment: The submit button name and value only gets send, when the form gets actually submitted via that button. In your `scount==0` case, you are not letting that happen though, you are preventing the normal form submission, and then you trigger submission with `$("#detail-form").submit()`. The latter does not send any submit button value (and why should it, it did not depend on any specific button to be clicked in the first place, you could have called that line of code from anywhere.)

Comment: @CBroe Is there any way I can send Submit button value while submitting through Jquery?

Comment: No easy one. But why would you need it? Instead of checking whether any arbitrary button was clicked, it would make much more sense to check whether the _other_ parameters of the form, the ones that you actually _need_, are set, or not.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I was thinking the same but just out of curiosity can I set a parameter value before submission using js or jquery?

Comment: You can populate a hidden field in the form before you call the submit method, so that name=value pair of that field will be send the same way an actual submit button would.